# Navbar in Bootstrap it opens, but it does not close on mobile

Tags: frameworks, navbar, show

My navbar on the phone opens, but it does not close.

```
        <div class="carousel-inner">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary nawigacja">
<div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">First tab</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#button1">2nd Tab</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#button2">3rd Tab</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#button3">4th tab</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#button4">5th Tab</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">6th Tab</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the elements I see that before clicking the code looks like this:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
```

and literally for a few seconds the code changes into:

```
navbar-collapse collapsing
```

next in 1 sec:

```
navbar-collapse collapse show
```

after another click it changes to

```
navbar-collapse collapsing
```

and after 1 sec again:

```
navbar-collapse collapse show
```

Navbar does not close at all after opening.

//edit:
I will add that on codeply it works.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix it.
For others who are struggling with the same problem, I will tell you that I had to remove the following from the  section:

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```